# error: expected primary-expression before ‘...’ token on gcc

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, g++

I was getting this compile error on gcc 10.3 :

```
<source>:15:22: error: expected primary-expression before '...' token
   15 |     void g() { a.f<Cs...>();}
      |                      ^~~
<source>:15:22: error: expected ';' before '...' token
   15 |     void g() { a.f<Cs...>();}
      |                      ^~~
      |                      ;
```

Turns out clang actually tells you what's wrong :

```
<source>:15:18: error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'f' as a dependent template name
    void g() { a.f<Cs...>();}
                 ^
                 template
```

[here's a minimum reproductible example](https://godbolt.org/z/53qa4dGrE) :

```cpp
template<typename ...Ts>
class A{
public:
    template<typename ...Cs>
    void f() {}
};

template<typename ...Ts>
class B{

    public:
    template<typename ...Cs>
    void g() { a.f<Cs...>();}

    private : 
    A<Ts...> a;
};
```

Comment: I think these are the solution: [CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html), [CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html)

Comment: im already doing :
`set_target_properties(chunk_manager PROPERTIES INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES cxx_std_20)` and                   
`set_target_properties(chunk_manager PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 20)`

Comment: You are doing smth wrong. The log file shows: -- Build type: Debug -- CXX_STANDARD: 11.

Comment: this is actually logs for a dependency  (fmt library). 
-- CPM: chunk_manager: adding package fmt@8.0.1 (8.0.1 to /home/runner/work/chunk_manager/chunk_manager/cpm_modules/fmt/b116ec18610f0c5e13500fecc7a23457fa963003)
-- Module support is disabled.
-- Version: 8.0.1
-- Build type: Debug
-- CXX_STANDARD: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to use use 'template' keyword to treat 'f' as a dependent template name like so :

```cpp
template<typename ...Cs>
void g() { a.template f<Cs...>();}
```